# How to display a 2 x 2 grid with div 1 and div 2 on top of each other in the first column, and div 3 in the second column spawing two rows

Tags: html, css, layout, grid

The following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>TITLE</title>
        <style>

        .a-block {
          background-color: #000066;
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
          grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
          padding: 10px;
          gap:10px;
        }
        .a-block > div {
          background-color: #FF0000;
          border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
          padding: 50px;
          gap: 10px;
         }
        .c_title {
          display:grid;
          grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2
          font-size: 2em;
          text-align: left;
          background-color: #FF0000;
          gap: 10px;
        }
        .c_body {
         display:grid;
          grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2
          font-size: 1.5em;
          text-align: justify;
          font-size: calc(1.5em + (1vw - 0.5em)); /* adapt font-size based on screen size */
          min-font-size: 0.8em; /* minimum font-size */
          background-color: #0000FF;
          gap: 10px;
        }
        .p_img  {
         display:grid;
         grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3
         background-color: #FF0000;
         gap: 10px;
        }
        .p_img  > img {
          object-fit: cover;
          width: 100%;
          max-height: 100%;
        }


        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>


            <div class="a-block" >
                <div class="c_title">title</div>
                <div class="c_body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                </div>
                <div class="p_img"  >
                        <img src="https://icatcare.org/app/uploads/2018/07/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png"  >
                </div>
            </div>



        <p></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Yields this result

[Rendered result in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DATeK.jpg)

Both divs I expect to be stacked over each other in the first column are on the first line.
The image I expect to be in the second column and spawning both rows is the second row  and first line

Looking at Chrome's inspector I can see my grid layout information is somehow ignored, but I did not find how to fix it

[Chrome inspector view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fihCx.jpg)

I tried many variations on grid layout and properties, but it keeps being ignored.

Comment: Don't use grid in every class just use it in main container. use span with grid-area and use ; semicolon at last. https://cssgridgarden.com/ check this link it will help you to understand grid. :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.a-block {
          background-color: #000066;
          display: grid;
          grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
          grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
          padding: 10px;
          gap:10px;
        }
        .a-block > div {
          background-color: #FF0000;
          border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
          padding: 50px;
          gap: 10px;
         }
        .c_title {
          font-size: 2em;
          text-align: left;
          background-color: #FF0000;
          gap: 10px;
        }
        .c_body {
          font-size: 1.5em;
          text-align: justify;
          font-size: calc(1.5em + (1vw - 0.5em)); /* adapt font-size based on screen size */
          min-font-size: 0.8em; /* minimum font-size */
          background-color: #0000FF;
          gap: 10px;
        }
        .p_img  {
         grid-area: 1 / 2 / span 2 / 2;
         background-color: #FF0000;
         gap: 10px;
        }
        .p_img  > img {
          object-fit: cover;
          width: 100%;
          max-height: 100%;
        }
```

```html
            <div class="a-block" >
                <div class="c_title">title</div>
                <div class="c_body">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                </div>
                <div class="p_img"  >
                        <img src="https://icatcare.org/app/uploads/2018/07/Thinking-of-getting-a-cat.png"  >
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: grid-area is contain row-start / column-start / row-end / column-end so you want it at start of 1 row and 1 column so first are 1 / 1 then you want  to end you row on 2nd row  and column so 1 / 1 / span 2 /  2.. span means you want to skip a row. span is important without span it will not take 2 rows

Comment: Thanks for your answer and link. The game changer was the missing semicolon!  I understand also the last "grid-area: 1 / 2 / span 2 / 2;" but "grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;" seems to work to.